# Split payload from JSON String

Tags: javascript, json

I receive these huge Strings via WebSocket:

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
  "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
]
```

or

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-36000-C",
  "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
]
```

or

```
[
  "BTC-31DEC21-60000-P",
  "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
]
```

I want to check for `isMasterFrame`

```
let payload = JSON.parse(messageString[1]);

if (payload.hasOwnProperty("isMasterFrame")) {
 for (let i = 0; i < payload.pairs.length; i++) {
   let currentPair = payload.data[i]
      currentPair = currentPair.replace(/\0/g, ''); //Remove null chars
       if (currentPair.toUpperCase() != 'KILL') {
           props.onAddAvailablePair(currentPair);
        }
       }
      } else {
             // print some output with payload which holds "isMasterFrame":false
     }
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Data from one inner pair: `{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}` should be split and inserted into the loop one by one

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Typo: It should be payload. **data** .length.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` after I updated the code.

Comment: That's not possible with this change and the rest of the code being what you showed . Please update the question. Also please consider using a debugger.

Comment: What do you mean by *"should be split and inserted into the loop one by one"*?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data has different structure when `isMasterFrame` is different. You have Object of `bids` and `asks` in data when `isMasterFrame` is `true` while it is an array when `isMasterFrame` is false.

```js
const data1 = [
    "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
    "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
  ],
  data2 = [
    "BTC-31DEC21-36000-C",
    "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
  ]
data3 = [
  "BTC-31DEC21-60000-P",
  "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
];

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((r, o) => {
      Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => {
        r[k] ??= [];
        r[k].push(v);
      });
      return r;
    }, {})
}

[data1, data2, data3].forEach(data => {
  const o = JSON.parse(data[1]);
  if(o.isMasterFrame) {
    const result = formatData(Object.values(o.data.bids));
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    const result = formatData(o.data);
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

You don't have property `pairs` inside **payload** object, so you can not access its `length`.

## Solution

You should iterate over `data` property. Since `data` property is also object, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function and iterate over its sub-properties.

```js
let payload = JSON.parse(messageString[1]);

if (payload.hasOwnProperty("isMasterFrame")) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(payload.data).length; i++) {
    let current_property= payload.data[Object.keys(payload.data)[i]];
    console.log(current_property);
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the code snippet below to see it in operation. I have also attached a screenshot of a console showing the output of values.

```js
// THIS IS AN ARRAY CONTAINING A JSON
var messageString = [
  "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
  "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
];

// THE JSON IS AT INDEX '1' OF THE ARRAY SO WE PARSE IT
let payload = JSON.parse(messageString[1]);

// YOU CAN SEE THE PARSED JSON IN CONSOLE
console.log(payload.data);

// SINCE isMasterFrame IS EITHER TRUE OR FALSE, WE CAN TEST FOR IT WITHOUT USING hasOwnProperty 
// IF isMasterFrame IS UNDEFINED OR NOT IN THE JSON, THE ELSE BLOCK WILL EXECUTE AND NOT BREAK THE CODE
if (payload.isMasterFrame) {
    console.log("1 payload.isMasterFrame: " + payload.isMasterFrame);
   // SINCE IT IS A JSON, WE HAVE TO LOOP THROUGH THE FIRST PART THIS WAY
    for (var key in payload.data) {
        if (payload.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("key base: " + key + " -> " + payload.data[key]);
            // SINCE THE VALUE IS ALSO A JSON OF VALUES, WE LOOP THROUGH AGAIN
            for (var key_inner1 in payload.data[key]) {
                if (payload.data[key].hasOwnProperty(key_inner1)) {
                    console.log("key inner1: " + key_inner1 + " -> " + payload.data[key][key_inner1]);
                    // GETTING THE CURRENT PAIR
                    let currentPair = payload.data[key][key_inner1];
                    console.log("CURRENT PAIR");
                    console.log(currentPair);
                    /*
                    currentPair = currentPair.replace(/\0/g, ''); //Remove null chars
                    if (currentPair.toUpperCase() != 'KILL') {
                        props.onAddAvailablePair(currentPair);
                    }
                    */

                    // SINCE THE VALUE IS ALSO A JSON OF VALUES, WE LOOP THROUGH AGAIN TO GET THE REAL VALUES
                    for (var key_inner2 in payload.data[key][key_inner1]) {
                        if (payload.data[key][key_inner1].hasOwnProperty(key_inner2)) {
                            // NOW WE CAN DO WHAT WE NEED TO WITH THE ACTUAL VALUES
                            console.log("key inner2: " + key_inner2 + " -> " + payload.data[key][key_inner1][key_inner2]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
} else {
    console.log("2 payload.isMasterFrame: " + payload.isMasterFrame);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. `pairs` property is not found inside object.
2. [String replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace a substring in a string with a new one. Here `currentPair` is a Object.If you try to replace any value of object just put if after `currentPair` ex: `currentPair.exchange.replace(/\0/g, '');`
3. `if (currentPair.toUpperCase() != 'KILL')` this condition is not clear to me, you may try to match `kill` with any object value. you may use like this `(currentPair.side.toUpperCase() != 'KILL')`

```js
     var messageString = [
             "BTC-31DEC21-60000-P",
             "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
         ]
    let payload = JSON.parse(messageString[1]);

    if (payload.hasOwnProperty("isMasterFrame")) {

        for (let i = 0; i < payload.data.length; i++) { //change here[1]
            let currentPair = payload.data[i]
            console.log(`current ${i} pair is- `,currentPair);
            // currentPair = currentPair.replace(/\0/g, ''); //change here[2]
            //  if (currentPair.toUpperCase() != 'KILL') { //change here[3] 
            //    props.onAddAvailablePair(currentPair);
            // }
        }
    } else {
        //print some output with payload which holds "isMasterFrame":false
    }
```

Output:

```
current 0 pair is-  {price: 0.105, volume: 0, exchange: 'DER', side: 'ASKS'}
current 1 pair is-  {price: 0.1055, volume: 28.7, exchange: 'DER', side: 'ASKS'}
current 2 pair is-  {price: 0.106, volume: 7.6, exchange: 'DER', side: 'ASKS'}
current 3 pair is-  {price: 0.1065, volume: 43, exchange: 'DER', side: 'ASKS'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I kinda cannot make heads and tails of what you are trying to achieve but here you have it.
your `payload.data` (and mine `decodedPayloadData.data`) is and object and not an array so `lenght` will throw error. That is why you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get array of elements from this object and then iterate it.

I have added `iterateObject()` function just to be fancy with displaying data.

```js
const data = [
    [
        "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
        "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
    ],
    [
        "BTC-31DEC21-36000-C",
        "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.422,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.423,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}]}"
    ],
    [
        "BTC-31DEC21-60000-P",
        "{\"data\":[{\"price\":0.105,\"volume\":0.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1055,\"volume\":28.7,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.106,\"volume\":7.6,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"},{\"price\":0.1065,\"volume\":43.0,\"exchange\":\"DER\",\"side\":\"ASKS\"}],\"isMasterFrame\":false}"
    ]
];

const iterateObject = (params) => {
    Object.entries(params).map(([name, value]) => {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            console.log('name:', name, '{');
            iterateObject(value);
            console.log('}');
        } else {
            console.log('name:', name, '; value:', value);
        }
    });
};

data.map(payload => {
    const decodedPayloadData = JSON.parse(payload[1]);

    if (decodedPayloadData.hasOwnProperty('isMasterFrame') && decodedPayloadData.isMasterFrame === true) {
        Object.entries(decodedPayloadData?.data ?? {}).map(([_, params]) => {
            if (typeof params === 'object') {
                iterateObject(params);
            } else {
                console.log('name:', name, '; value:', value);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('isMasterFrame is not defined or is not `true`');
    }
    console.log('----------------');
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: unset !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an object

```
const message = [
  "BTC-31DEC21-100000-P",
  "{\"data\":{\"bids\":{\"0.01\":{\"price\":0.01,\"volume\":66.2,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"5.0E-4\":{\"price\":5.0E-4,\"volume\":1.1,\"exchange\":\"DER\"},\"0.637\":{\"price\":0.637,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}},\"asks\":{\"0.664\":{\"price\":0.664,\"volume\":8.4,\"exchange\":\"DER\"}}},\"isMasterFrame\":true}"
]
const obj = JSON.parse(message[1])
console.log(obj["isMasterFrame"])
```

output:

```
True
```